# RemoteInput DelayUnit RemoteOutput = Howling?

Tags: xcode, core-audio

Hi I am developing iOS app using Audio Unit.
What I would like to do is to utter a voice using remote input, take a delay effect, and output it. However, the problem is that it makes howling since delayed voice is to be another "remote input" to the device and this situation does over again and again.

Could anyone give me advice how to keep the output from howling? I only need one repeated voice.
(Ex. if I utter "Hello", I can hear my uttered "Hello" from the device in 1or2 seconds. Recording is not preferable in my situation)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

What you're experiencing is [feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback).

Both OSX and iOS come with a special output audio unit called the AUVoiceProcessingIO which can help (it automatically performs the ducking that hotpaw2 describes). If you use it instead of the RemoteIO, it'll automatically duck the output when the input is triggered, which should cut down on or eliminate feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I tried using "kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO", but now I got no outputs, much less feedback issue.
I've just changed RemoteIO to VoiceProcessingIO and nothing else. Do I need to get/set some Properties along with this subtype, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try zeroing the input buffer when your audio output power (calculated from the output buffer contents) is above some threshold (that which causes feedback).  You might have to experiment with a short delay till when you stop zeroing the input to account for latencies.